# Error while invoking REST service

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, rest, cordova

I am facing a strange problem. I am trying to integrate a REST api in phonegap application.
When I request the url say *`http://myserver/index.php?m=login`* via a rest client in my browser it works fine.

But when I invoke it via jQuery ajax it returns the following error:

> Warning:
>   include(C:/Domains/my-portal.org/httpdocs/mmode/template/mobile/index.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in C:\Domains\my-portal.org\httpdocs\mmode\index.php on line 13
>
> Warning: include(C:/Domains/my-portal.org/httpdocs/mmode/template/mobile/index.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in C:\Domains\my-portal.org\httpdocs\mmode\index.php on line 13
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:/Domains/myportal.org/httpdocs/mmode/template/mobile/index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;./includes;./pear;C:\PHP\includes') in C:\Domains\my-portal.org\httpdocs\mmode\index.php on line 13

Now the problem is not cross-domain scripting because the response header returns "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`". And I have also *white-listed* the domain in cordova settings.

Can anyone please guide me what could be the problem here?

Comment: Its possible that you are actually getting these warnings on your browser, but due to the way it gets rendered, it may not be visible. This is a problem with the include in your script, It can't find one of the files.

Comment: since the api is not in my control is there any way to ignore these warnings and retrieve the actual response ?

Comment: It lookls like something tries to include PHP files that are located on a windows server and that are not present there.

Comment: problem is a path issue with your includes in php. What does include code look like? Is your `htttpdocs` folder really that deep into `C` drive?

Comment: Can you show us a little piece of your Javascript code who request the URL ?